# Java:When will the new component be shown on the screen?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

The following code is for update the UI. But when I debug the first line, I find that even it has been executed the frame is not updated right now. And I find if I doing some long-time calculations after those code, it won't change anymore and frame can't be closed.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);
((JPanel)frame.getContentPane()).revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

So my question is when exactly some changes in frame will be shown?

Answer (score 2):

when you tell it to by putting "this.setVisible(true);"

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. If I run this simple code `JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Key test");
  MyDrawPanel1 dp1 = new MyDrawPanel1(frame); frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible (true);
  JPanel p = new JPanel ();
  p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  p.add(dp1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.getContentPane().add(p);
  frame.pack();` When I add p to frame, it can show by  minimizing the window.

Comment: As I can see the changes should take effect instantly. To make them show at a particular time at a key/actionlistener which will update the frame when a given action is performed.

Answer (score 0):

> The following code is for update the UI.

I can't tell if you are trying to initially display the frame, or update the components on a currently visible frame.

If you are just trying to make the frame visible then the basic code is:

```
frame.add(...)
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

If you are trying to add components to a visible frame then the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

> I find if I doing some long-time calculations after those code...

The panel will be repainted right away, unless you have some code blocking the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`, which prevents the GUI from repainting itself.

> And I find if I doing some long-time calculations after those code,

This is an indication that you are blocking the `EDT`. You need to create a separate Thread for the long running task. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You can look into use a `SwingWorker` as discussed in the tutorial.